# is DOM manipulation (with jQuery or else) async?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using selectWithCircle function to select elements with jQuery and add a class 'active' to them.

```
var selectWithCircle = function(el){
    if(!el.hasClass('active')){
        el.addClass('active');
    }
}
```

then by doing another selection on the same elements I need to do something with them if the element has class 'active'

```
jQuery('label.ico-btn').click(function(event){
    var $this = jQuery(this);

    selectWithCircle($this);

    jQuery('label').each(function(index,item){//am I sure that this runs after selectWithCircle()?
      if(jQuery(item).hasClass('active')){
        //do something
      }
    });
 });
```

Am I sure that when I loop through the jQuery('label') selection the function selectWithCircle did its work?
More generally, is jQuery selection manipulation performed in Sync way?

Comment: I know I can put the jQuery('label'). each( ) code in selectWithCircle but here it's just an example.

Comment: Dom manipulation is synchronous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Setting the value of an input is synchronous. You will reliably get the updated value, cross-browser. Other DOM manipulations like inserting elements, removing them, moving them are also synchronous, although the user may not see the result until your JavaScript code completes, letting the browser use the thread to repaint the display.

And your code is works fine

Comment: What if I do it with pure JavaScript? I mean the code within the function.

Comment: Javascript is also synchronous

Answer (score 2):

JQuery is synchronous and single-threaded. If you run your code, the other will wait for it to success.

JQuery is only asynchronous in Ajax calls and it will not interrupt any other code that's currently running. Except the `async: false` option

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `jQuery` selection and decoration is done `synchronously`. Also all DOM manipulation is `synchronous` even if it may feel it isn't.