# Is jQuery.remove() really synchronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing the following code in a success block of an Ajax request:

```
$('#something').remove();
alert('something was removed');
```

When executed I expected it to finish removing 'something' and pop up an alert afterwards, but for some reason alert pops up and only after it's confirmed the element is removed.

Why does this happen? It's trivial code and I would like to avoid callbacks and such. What should I check?

It was tested on FF. Thanks for tips.

Comment: DOM is updated synchronously, maybe the page is not rendered before the alert?

Comment: Its offcourse synchronous

Comment: Try using `console.log` instead of `alert`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's a request from the customer, they want an alert. Is there some problem when using alert?

Comment: @Kos then it should be correctly handled by the browser/engine, no?

Comment: Try `$( document ).ready(function() {
    //your code
});` and then tell us what happen.

Comment: @Dropout No. Just don't use `alert`s. The DOM will typically only rerender after a script has finished updating it, and `alert()` does *block* that. Try using a DOM dialog instead, or put the alert in a `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Nolyurn it's a runtime thing, the page isn't static. This happens during the use of the app.

Comment: @Bergi I have to use an alert. This isn't my personal project.

Comment: If you still have a problem, you can use `setTimeout ` on your alert with a short delay, i think it's a bit weird but it'll may work as you wish, just an idea

Comment: @Nolyum that of course works, but IMHO using a timeout for such thing is even worse than using an alert in an app :)

Comment: @Dropout what do you mean by 'even worse'? You want to: 1. change the DOM, 2. free the thread to have the page painted, 3. block the thread and display an alert. That's a natural use case for `setTimeout(fn, 0)`

Comment: Would a zero timeout work? Is freeing the thread enough for it to work correctly? If this works, please provide it as an answer.

Comment: @Kos please read the above comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like Ivan Minakov [said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8445395/ivan-minakov), in order to see the page repainted before the alert, you have to let your JavaScript code complete. After this happens, you can schedule the continuation - displaying the alert.

Normally this doesn't happen in JavaScript - functions like alert and prompt are exceptional in the sense that they actually block the thread until the user acts.

This means that you can achieve what you want by:

```
$('#something').remove();
setTimeout(() => {
  alert('something was removed');
});
```

or with async/await if that's your thing:

```
// in an async function
$('#something').remove();
await delay(0);
alert('something was removed');

// ...somewhere...

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Comment: @Kos why it works only when `alert` is in setTimeout? At first I put `$('#something').remove()` into setTimeout (and not alert), but it didn't work.

Comment: @juice sounds like an unrelated problem, it should work

Comment: @Kos that's what I thought about your solution: it won't work either :D But then I tried it - just to be sure. And there IS a difference.

Answer (score 7):

As T.J. Crowder said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522561/is-javascript-synchronous-when-manipulating-the-dom):

> DOM manipulations (inserting elements, removing them, moving them) are
>   synchronous, although the user may not see the result until your
>   JavaScript code completes, letting the browser use the thread to
>   repaint the display.

Comment: So basically the alert is executed even before rendering happens as opposed to a custom modal window, which would wait for rendering because of itself having to be rendered? Just want to confirm.

Comment: @Dropout exactly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll upvote this because it's a great explanation, but I'll mark a workaround which @Kos mentioned as an answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Correctly said but I -1 because this answer is copied without even mentioning the original writer -
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/45482218/3933927

Comment: That doesn't make it any less valuable, but I digress.

Comment: @Stavm I think that specifically this particular part of the answer describes the current situation very well. And this is a good explanation of what is happening.

Comment: @IvanMinakov I did not say your answer isn't spot on, it is, problem is, it's not your answer. the original writer is left in the dark. that is very unethical - you could improve the answer, by adding a reference to that quote.

Comment: @Stavm Well. I am added link to question when conteins original phrase. And this is not link provided by you.